# Custom Segue With CATransition Not working

Tags: ios, storyboard, modal-dialog, segue, catransition

I'm trying to create a custom transition between my viewControllers. I'm following [this](http://blog.jambura.com/2012/07/05/custom-segue-animation-left-to-right-using-catransition/) tutorial but after clicking/tapping the button nothing happens!

This is the code for CustomSegue.m

```
#import "CustomSegue.h"
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"

@implementation CustomSegue

-(void)perform {
NSLog(@"ActionTest");

UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = .25;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom



[sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];
}

@end
```

The log is logged but no transition is performed nor the viewcontroller changes.
I have also changed the segue style to "custom" and class to "ZHCustomSegue"

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your custom segue in the storyboard? You can use ⌘⇧4

Comment: Did you change the segue type to ZHCustomSegue in the storyboard file?

Comment: @Can, unfortunately I need 10 reputation to upload a picture here so here is a link to the pic: http://s13.postimg.org/8pgyvfhl3/Screen_Shot_2013_07_22_at_10_41_57_AM.png

Comment: @codeinOrange, I believe I did here is a link to the image: http://s13.postimg.org/8pgyvfhl3/Screen_Shot_2013_07_22_at_10_41_57_AM.png

Comment: Also are you using a navigation controller?

Comment: @codeInOrange, No just a normal button that i connect to the next viewController using control+drag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the last two lines of your segue to this:

```
[destinationViewController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

You were trying to reference a navigation controller that wasn't there.

Comment: Turns out the key was in kCATransition